# KnockoutJS "if: " binding not working properly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
// Model
function User(item) {
  var self = this;
  this.id = ko.observable(item.id);
  this.name = ko.observable(item.name);
  this.surname = ko.observable(item.surname);
  this.email = ko.observable(item.email);
  // item.enabled is a boolean value.
  this.enabled = ko.observable(item.enabled);
  this.credit = ko.observable(new Credit(item.credit));
  this.roles = ko.observableArray(item.roles);
}    

<div data-bind='foreach: users'>
  <!-- This below prints 1 -->
  <span class='badge ' data-bind='text: enabled' ></span>

  <!-- Both of those below don't activate (if check fails) -->
  <span class='badge badge-success' data-bind='if: enabled==1'>OK</span>
  <span class='badge ' data-bind='if: enabled==0' >NO</span>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
<span class='badge badge-success' data-bind='if: enabled==1'>OK</span>
<span class='badge badge-success' data-bind='if: enabled'>OK</span>
<span class='badge badge-success' data-bind='if: enabled()'>OK</span>
<span class='badge badge-success' data-bind='if: enabled=="1"'>OK</span>
```

with no luck. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of your viewmodel? Are you sure `enabled` is an observable?

Comment: What is `enabled`? A string? A number? An observable?

Comment: Post the view model or better, add a fiddle.

Comment: I edited with model info. In the above code you see that enabled has value and is observable though, that's what i mean by saying "This below prints 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but the correct syntax is

```
<span class='badge badge-success' data-bind='if: enabled() == 1'>OK</span>
<span class='badge ' data-bind='if: enabled() == 0' >NO</span>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G6e4h/).

Because `enabled` is an observable (which is a function) you need to get its value by calling it without any parameters: `enabled()` when you are using it inside an expression.

Comment: Damn, you're right. But then... shouldn't 1 be evaluated true anyway!?

Comment: Yeah, the number 1 is treated as true and the number 0 is treated as false. So the `data-bind='if: enabled'` and `data-bind='if: disable` pair could work. But the string `"1"` is treated as true AND the string `"0"` is also treated as true. So I guess you have had strings in your `enabled` proeprty.